# Jquery Slider with multiple background colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi I have a jquery slider with one handle. I want to divide the slider into 3 equal parts so that each part has its own color. I don't think the jquery slider has that functionality and if not I was hoping someone can point me to any javascript based one that does.

Like this

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Tell us what you've done so far., Give us the link. Your code.,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go. You could do it by using **Bootstrap** + **JQuery UI Slider**. Let me know if this is what u want to achieve. Keep coding.

```js
$(function() { $("#slider").slider(); });
```

```css
.container { padding: 2vw; }

#slider { border: 1px solid white; }

.bg1, .bg2, .bg3 { height: 100%; }

.bg1 { background-color: salmon; }

.bg2 { background-color: green; }

.bg3 { background-color: #6dd5ff; }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <div id="slider">
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1 bg1"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1 bg2"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1 bg3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure CSS without JQuery-UI (if you wanted to avoid that). Thanks to css-tricks.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>

<style>
input[type=range] {
-webkit-appearance: none; /* Hides the slider so that custom slider can be made */
width: 300px; /* Specific width is required for Firefox. */
height:10px;
background: transparent; /* Otherwise white in Chrome */
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
-webkit-appearance: none;
background: white;
height: 30px;
width:30px;
border-radius:50%;
border:1px solid gray;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
outline: none; /* Removes the blue border. You should probably do some       kind of focus styling for accessibility reasons though. */
}

.foo {
width: 300px;
background:aqua;
z-index: -999;
border-radius: 8px;
}
.bar {
width:200px;
background: purple;
border-top-left-radius: 8px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}
.bas {
width:100px;
background: pink;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
I like sliders.
    <div class="foo">
        <div class="bar">
            <div class="bas">
                <input type="range" id="myRange" value="50">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I remember I look for this as well for my project (long and old project). Anyway, keywords sometimes important to be able to search it on Google Search Engine. "jQuery Color Slider Picker".

Try visit this: [jQuery Color Picker Sliders](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/jquery-colorpickersliders/)

I believe this is what you looking for.